# how to hide and show css class in ionic 2 with typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic2

We are using ionic 2 with typescript based hybrids mobile application and we are using third party library for chat messenger loading our application in one of the .ts file. The messenger always open post login and pre-login so we tried to hide that messenger using css but how can we do that in ionic 2 with typescript or else let me know any other alternative solution.

// loading our library in .ts file

```
ionViewDidLoad() {   
      var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 
      'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
      po.src = 'https://test/messanger/test/';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s); 
}
```

our requirement is we have to restricted pre-login in this features. I tried manually inspected to hide `(display:none)` for this but programatically (ionic 2 with typescript) we could not able to do it. Kindly help us to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

> [hidden]="true/false" attribute for hiding purpose
>   in template

or

> *ngIf="true/false" (this will show the template only if *ngIf is true)

Comment: I am loading that chat message library in typescript only so how can i use in template. normally that chat functionality don't use any template. once load above that script in typescript it will automatically load the chat pages. for example google map we are loading same way but there is one option for <div> tags so we can easily control.

Comment: i got one idea is i have another one option i founded while inspect the google chrome to hide the chat message icon / box (display : none ) but normal programatically we can use but typescript how can i load the display none .